# Apache Custom Error Log Entry

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, apache2, custom-errors

I have a rule in my Apache config like this:

```
<FilesMatch "xyz">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
 ErrorDocument 403 "Custom Response"
</FilesMatch>
```

In the error log it will always add an entry like:

```
[Fri Apr 14 09:46:10.706192 2023] [access_compat:error] [pid 12345] [client 93.184.216.34:47540] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/example.com/xyz
```

Is there any way to add a custom error message there in the log? I'd like to either alter, append to the existing error message or add an additional log entry with a text string specified in my config file.

I looked at using [Custom Log Formats](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html) and it does seem to accept environment variables, but I'm unclear if I can use it to accomplish my goal.

I also looked into Apache's [Error](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#error) directive, but this doesn't seem possible due to the fact that "*this directive cannot be conditonally evaluated*'